# What's the difference between навлечь and привлечь?

Tags: словоупотребление, лексикон

What's the difference between those two words? Can i use only влечь?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

• *Привлечь* (perfective) and *привлекать* (imperfective) is a stylistically neutral aspect pair of verbs with wide usage meaning "to attract (attention, funds, but not in physical sense, like magnets attract iron)". The deverbal adjective is *привлекательный* "attractive (about a person, a place)".

> *Не шуми, а то **привлечёшь** их внимание*. 'Be quiet or you'll **attract** their attention.'
>
> *Тебя **не привлекает** перспектива поиграть с нами в покер?* — 'The prospect of playing poker with the two of us **doesn't appeal** to you?'

Also, this pair of verbs has a judiciary meaning when used in the phrase *привлечь к ответственности* 'to prosecute, to bring to account':

> *За некоторые преступления можно **привлечь к ответственности** лишь при наличии иска пострадавшей стороны.* — 'Some of the crimes could only be **prosecuted** in response to a complaint by the aggrieved party.'

• *Навлечь* (perfective) and *навлекать* (imperfective) is archaic, used mostly in idiomatic phrases, ***навлечь** что-то (Acc.) **на** кого-то (Acc.)*, like "*навлечь на себя их гнев*" — 'draw their wrath unto oneself'. Things one can *навлечь* are limited to a rather short list, they are *гнев* 'wrath', *беда, несчастье*,'disaster', *подозрение* 'suspicion', *опасность* 'danger', *неприятности* 'troubles, problems' — all kinds of nasty undesirable things.

> *Что же ты натворила, чтобы **навлечь** такой гнев?* — 'So... what did you do to incur that much wrath?'

• *Влечь* (imperfective only, no perfective pair without a prefix) has very limited usage. It is either bookish and elevated, like *его **влечёт** наука* 'he is **drawn** to science', or official and judiciary, usually *влечь за собой* 'to entail, to lead to':

> *Нарушение международных обязательств государством должно **влечь за собой** ответственность.* — 'The breach of international obligations by a State must **entail** accountability.'
>
> *Привитие детям навыков собственной защиты является необходимостью, однако это не должно **влечь за собой** какую-либо правовую ответственность родителей или детей*. — 'The education of children for their own protection is necessary but should not **lead to** any legal responsibility for parents or children.'

The deverbal noun is *влечение* which is '(sexual) attraction, desire (sexual or to alcohol, drugs, food, etc.)':

> *Встречаешь кого-то и возникает сильное **влечение** друг к другу.* — 'Meet someone and - and have that... intense **attraction** right away.'
>
> *Когда люди влюблены, это **влечение** обоюдное.* — 'In love there's mutual **attraction**.'
>
> *У меня непреодолимое **влечение** просто... к пиву*. — 'I've got a burning **desire** for just... a beer.'

To sum it up, it is **not recommended** to use *навлекать, навлечь, влечь* unless you are absolutely sure you know what exactly it is going to mean. Remember, *навлекать, навлечь, влечь* are used mostly **in idioms** and lawspeak, it is very easy to live without ever using those verbs.

Comment: I would add that in a negative connotation, instead of using "niche" words "навлечь/повлечь", one can normally use "привести к" (lead to).

Answer (score 1):

No, you cant use only `влечь`

`Привлечь` - arouse interest by another people (or animals). You can attract only those who can see you.

`Навлечь` - attract problems